# Add date to url of blog page

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm building my first wagtail django site. My site has a blogging part and I'd like to add the publish date in the url. Currently, when adding a page, the URL becomes: example.com/blog/[slug] but I want it to be: example.com/blog/2015/11/19/[slug]

My blogpage:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    main_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + (
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        ImageChooserPanel('main_image'),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

Comment: Do you know how to pass variables into the url? I can help with that part but I do not know how to extract specific parts of the date and put them in the url.

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/

Comment: I don't have a full solution to hand, but I'd suggest looking at custom `route` methods http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.2/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#adding-endpoints-with-custom-route-methods, or possibly doing something with `RoutablePageMixin`: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.2/reference/contrib/routablepage.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can integrate this with wagtail but here is an example of how you can achieve with django :

1. Update your model to generate automatically the slug (**E.g** : based on title) in `blog/models.py` :

```python
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Post(models.Model):
    # your attributes
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now())
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self):
        """
        Generate and save slug based on title
        """
        super(Post, self).save()
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save()
```

2. Add a new url in your blog app (`blog/urls.py`) :

```python
url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', views.post_details)
```

3. Define the view to get the post in `blog/views.py` :

```python
def post_details(request, year, month, day, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug, date__year=year, date__month=month, date__day=day)
    # do what you want with this post
```

Comment: Use below RegEx for single and two digit month and day values :

Comment: url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$'
        , views.post_details),

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more Wagtail specific way to implement this solution, it assumes you also have a BlogIndexPage that contains all the blog pages underneath. Although this would work even if your BlogPages exist under the HomePage, just move your route method accordingly.

Overview:

- We will be updating the sub-URLs on the BlogPageIndex (or whatever page that your blog pages are located within). We do this by adding the mixin [RoutablePageMixin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html#module-wagtail.contrib.wagtailroutablepage).
- We can then use `@route` as a decorator over a method on BlogPageIndex for any kind of custom views we want.
- Finally, we need to update our BlogPage model so its normal URL will follow our new URL mapping. We do this by overriding the `set_url_path` on our BlogPage.
- This will use the normal `slug` field from the BlogPage model and the field `date_published` to generate the new `url_path`.

See example /myapp/models.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models import RoutablePageMixin, route
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page


class BlogPage(Page):
    # using date_published instead of date to reduce ambiguity
    date_published = models.DateField(
        "Date post published", blank=True, null=True
    )
    # ...other fields:  main_image, intro, body
    # ...search_fields
    # ...content_panels

    # override the set_url_path method to use generate different URL
    # this is updated on save so each page will need to be re-published
    # old URL will still work
    def set_url_path(self, parent):
        # initially set the attribute self.url_path using the normal operation
        super().set_url_path(parent=parent)
        self.url_path = self.url_path.replace(
            self.slug, '{:%Y/%m/%d/}'.format(self.date_published) + self.slug
        )


class BlogIndexPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    # note - must inherit RoutablePageMixin AND Page

    # ...other fields
    # ...search_fields
    # ...content_panels

    # route for sub-pages with a date specific URL for posts
    # this will NOT make a list of pages at blog/2018 just specific blogs only
    @route(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/?$')
    def blog_page_by_date(self, request, year, month, day, slug, name='blog-by-date'):
        """Serve a single blog page at URL (eg. .../2018/01/23/my-title/)"""
        blog_page = get_object_or_404(
            BlogPage,
            date_published__year=year,
            date_published__month=month,
            date_published__day=day,
            slug=slug
        )
        return blog_page.serve(request)

    # Speficies that only BlogPage objects can live under this index page
    subpage_types = ['BlogPage']
```

Caveats:

- Each existing blog page will need to be re-saved to trigger the updates to the url_path.
- The original url_path will still work and **not** redirect, it is possible to add a redirect by overriding the [`serve`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method) method and checking if an old URL has been used, then redirect.
- This does not consider any SEO implications of having multiple URLs for pages.